# Bootstrap with dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown

I'm writing a simple code using bootstrap for dropdown menu, the code seems fine. However, it doesn't expand when I clicked on the caret. I'm not sure what goes wrong. Can someone help me with this? Thanks for the help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>thenewboston</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a href="navbar.html" class="navbar-brand">ABE TECHNOLOGY</a>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Menu Items -->
    <div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      
      <!-- drop down menu -->
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to load the jquery plugin as I mention on my answer below? If Did that help?

Comment: I did added the jQuery in, but when I ran chrome or firefox it didn't work. However, when I ran the same code on jsfiddle.com, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh, nvm. I used your jQuery and the minified javascript code then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are not loading the jQuery plugin!!

You need to load this script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For [Bootstraps javascript components](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-overview) you will need to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

You have to include jQuery **before** the Bootstraps scripts. Best is, you include both scripts at the bottom of your page, right before the closing `</body>` tag like:

```
[...your html...]

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reasons, the jQuery you sent is not working, but @BigDropGR works fine. Thanks for the help though.